# installing MySQLdb for Python 2.7 on OSX gives an IndexError

Tags: python, macos, mysql-python

I am trying to install MySQLdb in python 2.7 and it gives me following error on running setup.py file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 16, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/Users/hhamza/Desktop/MySQL-python-1.2.2/setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
    libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
  File "/Users/hhamza/Desktop/MySQL-python-1.2.2/setup_posix.py", line 7, in dequote
    if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Does anyone know what am i missing here?